# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Activity Monitor

Tags: database, sql-server-2000

I tried to turn on the Activity Monitor using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio (SSMS) through the options window of the application (Tools | Options | Environment | General | At Startup).

I restarted SSMS and I am getting the following message:

"This operation does not support connections to Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition version 8.00.2249."

I need to be able to monitor the processes and activities inside the database since I am investigating a particular application which takes a lot of time in its database data retrieval access and I am thinking it may be due to some locks or some processes.

How do I resolve this?  Inputs highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Activity Monitor relies on DMVs that were introduced in SQL Server 2005. You cannot monitor a SQL 2000 instance. Your version number (8.00.2249) is for a SQL Server 2000, a product no longer supported ([mainstream support retired 4/8/2008](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&x=13&y=8&p1=2852)). Upgrade the instance to SQL Server 2008.

If you want to investigate a SQL 2000 instance, you'll have to rely on the old views and procedures: [sysprocesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260456%28SQL.80%29.aspx), [sp_who](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260384%28SQL.80%29.aspx), [sp_lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238824%28SQL.80%29.aspx). See [INF: Understanding and resolving SQL Server blocking problems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224453).

Comment: Would you add further information on how I would be able to monitor the locks using the stored procedures which you indicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SQL 2000 does not have Dynamic management views that feed this info to the activity monitor

Run **sp_who2** instead, it is not as rich as the activity monitor but it will tell you who is connected and who is blocking. You can then also run something like **DBCC INPUTBUFFER** (SPID) to get the first 255 characters of the statement executed by the sql connection